# Unable to manipulate click in IFrame using Android WebDriver

Tags: android, node.js, iframe, appium

I am writing a test for a hybrid app which contains a iframe inside a webview and I'm trying to click a button inside the iframe.

It worth mentioning that the data inside the iframe is in another origin. Nevertheless, I managed to switch to the iframe and I can see the content of it (also getting element).

This is the sequence of commands I run

```
return driver
  .contexts().then(function (contexts) { 
    return browser.context(contexts[1]); // choose the webview context
   }) 
  .frame('myFrame") //switch to iframe
  .getElementById('myButton')
  .click() //try to click button
```

It work fine on an iOS simulator, but on the Android it does nothing. The test continues to run, but no action is made.

I'm running **Appium 1.2.2** with **nodejs wd** client and **Genymotion 2.2.2**
I also tried it on a real android device and on the Andorid SDK emulator - none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to work around it. I used xpath to find the element and then used `tapElement()` to make the magic happen.

```
return driver
  .contexts().then(function (contexts) { 
    return browser.context(contexts[1]); // choose the webview context
  }) 
  .frame('myFrame") //switch to iframe
  .elementByXPath('//li[div/span[contains(text(),"Data I want")]]')
  .then(function(el){
    return driver.tapElement(el);
  })
```

I opened an issue about it in [appium's github](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/3759) and will also open one in wd's github.

### Update:

You can chain the element method using `.tap()`:

```
  .elementByXPath('//li[div/span[contains(text(),"Data I want")]]')
  .tap()
```